# how do I mock out http post in Angular without using TestBed?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, rxjs

How do I unit test this login function, specifically the http post part?  The http mock I made is not coded correctly to get into the 'if...else' section of the code.  I dont want to use TestBed.  TestBed is too slow.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('https://blah/api/login',
      JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;
            if (token) {
                this.token = token;
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(this._serverError);
}

private _serverError(err: any) {
    return Observable.throw(err || 'backend server error');
}
```

---

Below is the Jasmine test Im attempting: I need help with this line.

```
spyOn(mockHttp,'post').and.returnValue(Observable.of(response));
```

What should my returnValue be to get my inside of the 'if...else' code in the login function?

```
    describe('AuthenticationService', () => {
      let service: AuthenticationService;
      let mockHttp = null;

      beforeEach(() => {
        mockHttp = {};
        mockHttp.post = function(){};
        service = new AuthenticationService(mockHttp);
     });

    it(`should set access token in local storage for successful login`,() => {
      const access_token = 'blah83balc380';
      const responseOptions =  new ResponseOptions();
      responseOptions.status = 200;
      responseOptions.body = {access_token:access_token};
      const username = 'test';
      const currentUserExpected = JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: access_token });
      var response = new Response(responseOptions);
      spyOn(mockHttp,'post').and.returnValue(Observable.of(response));
      service.login(username, 'test');
      var currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
      expect(currentUserExpected).toEqual(currentUser);
    });
  });
```

Comment: What would make you want to do a thing like that? It requires you to mock `json()` function, etc. It's just cumbersome. Since you can't handle it, this can be considered a proof that testing with TestBed is superior. Btw, code formatting is wrong, the question is unreadable.

Comment: @estus TestBed tests are slow.  How long does it take to run 100 tests that use TestBed?  too long.  That's why I dont want to use TestBed unless absolutely necessary.  Testing with TestBed is not superior.  Your comment is useless and unhelpful.

Comment: If you don't appreciate it this doesn't make the comment useless. How efficient 100 tests are if they don't provide full coverage? You can test DI properly with TestBed. You can't do that without it. There's not even a mention that you have problems with performance in the question... wait, there is a mention, but it's not visible because of bad formatting.

Comment: You should read https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-testing-guide-a485b6cb1ef0

Comment: @Maxime thanks!   that article is a great summary and is exactly what I needed

Comment: @estus  you were mostly correct in your first comment.  TestBed testing is mostly superior.  I can write unit tests that run slightly faster without using TestBed, but, the amount of time it takes to figure out how to write tests without TestBed can be long.  I ran some benchmarks on suites of tests with and without using TestBed.  I will post the results of the benchmarks below.

Comment: I understand your concerns. Even if TestBed is desirable, it doesn't hurt to know your options. Considering that there's a number of TestBed tests to test DI (and they should be there), the rest of tests can be performed without it. If there's not too much Http tests, it may be more comfortable to test them with TestBed and MockBackend any way. I provided the answer on how it may look like without MockBackend.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer that I ended up using. I was using TestBed in a way that was slow when I could have been using TestBed like the code below:

```
import { TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule,  XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/authentication.service';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('AuthenticationService', () => {
  let mockbackend, service;

  beforeEach(() => {
    localStorage.clear();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpModule ],
      providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([AuthenticationService, XHRBackend], (_service, 
_mockbackend) => {
    service = _service;
    mockbackend = _mockbackend;
  }));

  it('should set access token in local storage for successful login', () => 
 {
    const access_token = 'blah83balc380';
    const username = 'test';
    const currentUserExpected = JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: access_token });
    const response = {access_token: access_token};
    const responseOptions = new ResponseOptions();
    responseOptions.body = JSON.stringify(response);
    mockbackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(responseOptions));
    });
    service.login(username, 'test').subscribe(respond => {
      expect(respond).toEqual(true);
      const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
      expect(currentUserExpected).toEqual(currentUser);
    });
  });

it('should not set access token in local storage for unsuccessful login', () =>     {
    const username = 'test';
    const responseOptions = new ResponseOptions();
    responseOptions.body = '';
    responseOptions.status = 401;
    const response = new Response(responseOptions);
    response.ok = false;
    response.statusText = 'Unauthorized';
    response.type = 2;

    mockbackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(response);
    });
    service.login(username, 'test').subscribe(respond => {
      expect(respond).toEqual(false);
    }, err => {
      const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
      expect(currentUser).toEqual(null);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I was only using TestBed.createComponent for every test, which I didnt need to do.  TestBed.createComponent is slow, but the approach in the answer is fast....well, fast enough.

Comment: Hello, I have tried to implement your solution but I am facing some error. Can you please look into this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494266/implement-unit-testing-with-jasmine-karma-by-mocking-http-post-angular-5

Answer (score 0):

You can inject services into your test like

```
it('should do something',inject([YourService,XHRBackend],(service:YourService,mockBackend)=>{
 mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection)=>{
   connection.mockRespond(new Response({body:JSON.stringify('your mock response')});
```

...

this will cause your post call to return with that mock data.  What I am not certain of though is if you can actually inject XHRBackend without first doing a testbed and providing

```
{provide: XHRBackend, useClass:  MockBackend}
```

Comment: I tried this approach a few days ago.  I couldnt get the 'provide' to work without using TestBed.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

`TestBed` is generally preferable way to test Angular services.

Despite what the official guide says,

> Isolated unit tests examine an instance of a class all by itself without any dependence on Angular or any injected values. The tester creates a test instance of the class with new, supplying test doubles for the constructor parameters as needed, and then probes the test instance API surface.
>
> You should write isolated unit tests for pipes and services.

isolated tests don't address DI testing. When a class is instantiated with `new`, its DI decorators (`@Injectable`, `@Inject`) are not tested.

`Http` tests are also easier to write and maintain when `MockBackend` is involved.

When performance becomes a real concern, some tests can be converted from `TestBed` to isolated. In this case `Http` API should be replicated with Jasmine mocks. In order to get full coverage, all functions calls should be tested. The test will look like

```
  mockHttp = jasmine.createSpyObj(['post']);
  service = new AuthenticationService(mockHttp);
  ...

  it(..., fakeAsync(async () => {
    const bodyMock = { access_token: 'foo' };
    const responseMock = { json: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(bodyMock) };
    const responseMock$ = Observable.of(responseMock);
    mockHttp.post.and.returnValue(responseMock$);
    
    const login$ = service.login(...);
    
    expect(mockHttp.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    const postArgs = callback.calls.first().args;
    expect(postArgs).toEqual([..., ..., jasmine.any(RequestOptions));
    
    const requestOptions = postArgs[2];
    expect(requestOptions.headers).toEqual(jasmine.any(Headers));
    expect(Array.from(requestOptions.headers._headers)).toEqual([
      ['Content-Type', ['application/json']],
      ['accept', ['application/json']]
    ]);
    
    expect(login$).toEqual(jasmine.any(Observable));
    const login = await login$.toPromise();

    expect(responseMock.json).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(service.token).toBe('foo');
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
    expect(login).toBe(true);
  }));
```

Then another test is performed with `bodyMock` that doesn't have `access_token`.

It should be noticed that `localStorage` should be stubbed as well in order to be properly tested. For testability reasons it's beneficial to use local storage service via DI instead.