# Does this angular 4 unit test meet current convention?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I'm unit testing a basic `@Injectable` service in ng 4.  Tutorials use varying conventions (for example the use of `TestBed` vs `debugElement.injector`).  While these tests pass, my setup feels cobbled together and probably uses bad conventions.

**Here are my concerns:**

1. The declaration of `providers` seems verbose, but `providers: [MockProgressServer]` led to a karma error.
2. Should the first test `expect(component).ToBeTruthy` always be included when testing a component?  This seems autogenerated by ng cli in other modules.
3. The line `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProgressService)` seems itnerchangible with `TestBed.get(ProgressService)`.  Which is preferrable?
4. Should tests like this always be declared as `async()` as a rule of thumb?

---

The class we're testing is `ProgressService` in `progress.service.ts`.  It is trivial and contains a single `currentState` field with `getters` and `setters`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ProgressService {
    private currentState: string = '1';

    constructor() {
    }

    setCurrentState(state: string) {
        this.currentState = state;
    }

    getCurrentState(){
        return this.currentState
    }    
}
```

Because this class is trivial, the corresponding `Mock` overrides nothing.

```
import {ProgressService} from "../../../progress.service";

export class MockProgressService extends ProgressService {
}
```

I've cobbled together the following `progress.spec.ts` class to unit test the getters and setters.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProgressComponent } from './progress.component';
import {MockProgressService} from "../shared/services/progress/progress.mock1";
import {ProgressService} from "../progress.service";

describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let component: ProgressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>;
  let mockService: ProgressService;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProgressComponent ],
      providers: [{provide: ProgressService, useValue: new MockProgressService()}]
    }).compileComponents()

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProgressService)

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('The component should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('ProgressService default currentState is "1"', () =>{
    expect(mockService.getCurrentState()).toEqual('1')
  })

  fit('ProgressService new currentState is "5"', () =>{
    mockService.setCurrentState('5')
    expect(mockService.getCurrentState()).toEqual('5')
  })
});
```

`npm test` shows that these pass

[image]

Thanks.  I want to get this locked down before moving on to non-trivial cases.

PS, is there any way to change the styling of the Karma browser report?  (EG make the font bigger?)

### Updated solution based on estus answers

Split test modules.  **First, test the service:**

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, getTestBed, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProgressComponent } from './progress.component';
import {ProgressService} from "../progress.service";

describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: ProgressService;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     providers: [ProgressService]
    }).compileComponents()

    injector = getTestBed()
    service= injector.get(ProgressService)    

  });    
  fit('ProgressService default currentState is "1"', () =>{
    expect(service.getCurrentState()).toEqual('1')
  })

  fit('ProgressService new currentState is "5"', () =>{
    service.setCurrentState('5')
    expect(service.getCurrentState()).toEqual('5')
  })
});
```

*Two things:*

1. Is my use of provider/TestBed.get() correct?  Why couldn't I just instantiate an instance of ProgressService myself?  Does the TestBed ensure that a singleton is created?
2. Not sure where your suggestion of `fakeAsync` would fit in...

Next, **test the component**:

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, getTestBed, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing'

import { ProgressComponent } from './progress.component'
import {MockProgressService} from "../shared/services/progress/progress.mock1"
import {ProgressService} from "../progress.service"

describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let injector: TestBed
  let mockService: ProgressService
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>
  let component: ProgressComponent

  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProgressComponent ],
      providers: [{provide: ProgressService, useClass: MockProgressService}]
    }).compileComponents()

    injector = getTestBed()
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    mockService = injector.get(ProgressService)

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   fit('The component should be created', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });

   fit('The service should be an instance of MockService', () => {
     expect(mockService instanceof MockProgressService).toBeTruthy()
   })
});
```

Comment: The style belongs to Jasmine HTML report and not Karma. I'm not sure what's would be a good way to provide additional CSS to it. I guess Ctrl+`+` should do the job, shouldn't it? Usually people don't use browser report for Karma, so it's rarely a problem.

Comment: True, was mostly just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a service test shouldn't have `declarations` and `TestBed.createComponent`. A component creates extra moving part and may affect test results. And `ProgressService` certainly doesn't need to be mocked in its own test. Actually, `ProgressService default currentState`, etc and `The component should be created` belong to two different test bed setups. The one has `providers: [ProgressService]`, the another has `declarations: [ ProgressComponent ]` and `MockProgressService`.

---

The use of `providers: [MockProgressService]` is incorrect here, because DI token that is in use is `ProgressService`, and this provider has to be mocked. `providers` are supposed to be:

```
providers: [{provide: ProgressService, useClass: MockProgressService}]
```

`expect(component).ToBeTruthy` assertion is not necessary but may be useful because there are some conditions in testing environment that can make `beforeEach` block silently fail, while `The component should be created` test is the one that can determine this problem unambiguously.

`fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProgressService)` can be safely replaced with `TestBed.get(ProgressService)` *here*, and this is what `TestBed.get` and `inject` helpers are for. But those two *aren't interchangeable* because `TestBed.get` retrieves service instance from root injector, while `fixture.debugElement.injector` is component injector and can access instances that are specific to a component. Also, there won't be `fixture` if this is test bed without a component.

As a rule of thumb, tests should use `fakeAsync` helper - just because it causes zero delay and does the job. It should work out of the box. If there is a test that is truly asynchrounous (e.g. loaded templates), `fakeAsync` will cause a meaningful error that suggests to change it to `async`.

Comment: I updated my solution to reflect your comments.  Did I capture your suggestions correctly?

Comment: I guess you did. `fakeAsync` suggestion means that the blocks are defined with it by default, `beforeEach(fakeAsync(...))` and `it(fakeAsync(...))` - not with `async`. `TestBed.get` or `inject` also test constructor DI annotation, something that won't be tested when you do `new ProgressService()` manually. However, once you've tested the class in TestBed suite, you can test it in another suite without TestBed if you have reasons to do this. e.g. [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119057/3731501)